# NodeJs: How to repeatedly call an API every 15min

Tags: node.js

I need to get a stock price from an API and save it to the database every 15min whats the best way to do this?

My first thought was to use node-fetch with a setInterval but I'm not sure this is best practice. Or maybe a cron job with node-cron?

Comment: `setInterval()` and the `request-promise` library for making the http request is one option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) can work, but you will lose the scheduled tasks if the server goes down. I have used schedulers like [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda) extensively in the past and benefits from having a persistence layer.

For example:

```
agenda.define('getStockPrice', async job => {
  const data = await stockeService.getPrice();
  ...
});

agenda.every('15 minutes', 'getStockPrice');
```

Checkout the [docs](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#readme) for more info.

Comment: Why use an external package in place of a simple 15 minute timer?

Comment: @jfriend00 "will lose the scheduled tasks if the server goes down."

Comment: So, you're saying that agenda somehow automatically runs when your server restarts?  You could also just have a `setInterval()` in the startup code when your server restarts too.  I'm just trying to understand what's the advantage of using an external package for such a simple problem.  This isn't dozens of scheduled tasks at all various times.  It's just one recurring polling operation.

Comment: @jfriend00 as I stated in the answer **"node-cron can work"**, as will setInterval. The issue comes about if you schedule tasks and node restarts - you lose the scheduled tasks that were expected to run at the given times/intervals. This may/may not be important. Yes, agenda persists the jobs and data to run at defined times. Just a recommendation in addition to normal scheduling.

Comment: I guess if you wanted the job to run every 6 hours but the server restarted every 5 hours then the job would never run. Or if want a job to run every Monday at 9am GMT then agenda is the way to go

Comment: @Bill yes exactly, really depends on the requirement and importance of the job running at the defined intervals/schedule times.

Comment: Yeah, I get it for more complex things - pretty handy.  Updating a price every 15 minutes doesn't seem like that type of problem.  If the server restarts, you update the price when it starts and set a new interval for 15 minutes.  It's just a simple problem in that way.  That's why I asked what were the advantages for this particular problem of using an external library.

Comment: if the server was to restart after 14min would the task never run, leaving the data out of sync for 30min?

Comment: Every 15min from scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

Use cron job
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron`

It's a best way to run the api or any function every time which we want to.

The node-cron module is tiny task scheduler in pure JavaScript for node.js based on GNU crontab. This module allows you to schedule task in node.js using full crontab syntax.

Comment: But why is it better than using pure `setInterval()`?